# Slow graphic performance

Tags: drivers, graphics, games, steam, intel

I'm new on ubuntu, and I have a problem with graphic, or graphic driver.
Recently, I installed Steam (app, not steam os) on my ubuntu 14.04 machine, after downloading all of my games, I noticed that I can't play any game, because of extremely slow pc performance. Which is strange, cos when I use the same laptop, with HDD with installed windows 7, every game runs great on high or medium graphic settings on 720p screen resolution. On ubuntu, even on low graphic settings, and 800x600 screen resolution, games are just unplayable.

So I guess that I don't have proper graphic driver installed? And how can I do that?

My pc is Asus x54c with Intel HD 3000 integrated graphic.

Any suggestion? Thx!

Comment: Please execute the command `glxinfo | grep renderer` and add the output of the command to your question.  You may need to execute `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` first.

Answer (score 0):

When I execute first command, this is what i got:

GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile

On second command I got this:

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mesa-utils is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25 linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
  python-dateutil python3-tz
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.